# if cell equal to the cell below then perform an action in R

Tags: r

In R I am trying to go through a df and if the data in a column matches the data in the row below it, make the data from another column match too. I haven't really got to far other then considering a FOR loop such as below. Other options are to use an if statement but I'm sure there is a better way.

```
For (row in 1:nrow(df)){ insert code here maybe}
```

An example of my data is below

```
id  name
1    M1
2    M1
3    M1
4    M2
5    M2
```

I would like it to look like this

```
id  name
1    M1
1    M1
1    M1
4    M2
4    M2
```

Answer (score 2):

We group by 'name' and `mutate` to 'id' to get the `first` element of 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(id = first(id))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, id := first(id), by = name]
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df1$id <- with(df1, ave(id, name, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:5, name = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2"
  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. New there was away round it without loops and if statements. :), never would have got to that.